# Web scraping through multiple pages doesnt save each result -beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My problem is, it loops through pages, but it doesn't write anything into my list.

At the end I print `len(title)` and it is still 0.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for page in range(20, 200, 20):
    current_page = 'https://auto.bazos.sk/{}/?hledat=kolesa&hlokalita=&humkreis=&cen'.format(page)
    web_req = requests.get(current_page).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(current_page).content, 'html.parser')

    title_data = soup.select('.nadpis')
    title = []
    for each_title in title_data:
        title.append(each_title.text)
    print(current_page)

print(len(title))
```

Comment: What happens with you print each_title.text? If this is the text content expected something is likely wrong with your .append method. If not, try printing where that originates etc etc to find the root cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `title` out of the `loop` and there you have it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

title = []
for page in range(20, 40, 20):
    current_page = 'https://auto.bazos.sk/{}/?hledat=kolesa&hlokalita=&humkreis=&cen'.format(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(current_page).content, 'html.parser')
    title_data = soup.select('.nadpis')
    for each_title in title_data:
        title.append(each_title.text)
    print(current_page)
print(title)
```

Output:

```
['ELEKTRONY SKODA OCTAVIA SCOUT DISKY “PROTEUS” R17', 'Fiat Sedici 1.6, 4x4, r.v 04/2009, 79 kw, slovenské ŠPZ', 'Bmw e46 328ci', '255/50 R19', 'Honda Jazz 1.3', 'Predám 4 ks kolesá', 'Audi A5 3.2 FSI quattro tiptronic  S LINE R20  TOP STAV', 'Peugeot 407 combi 1,6 hdi', 'Škoda Superb 2.0TDI 4x4 od 260€ mesačne, bez akontácia', 'Predam elektrony Audi 5x112 R17 a letne pneu', 'ROZPREDÁM MAZDA 3 2.0i 110kW NA NÁHRADNÉ DIELY', 'Predám Astra j Turbo Noblesse bronz', 'ŠKODA KAROQ  1.6 TDI - full výbava', 'VW CHICAGO 5x112 + letné pneu 215/40 R18', 'Fiat 500 SPORT 1.3 multijet 70kw', 'Volvo FL280 - TROJSTRANNÝ SKLÁPAČ + HYDRAULICKÁ RUKA', 'ŠKODA SUPERB COMBI 2.0 TDI 190K 4X4 L&K DSG', 'FORD FOCUS 2.0 TDCI TITANIUM', 'FORD EDGE 2.0 TDCi - 154 kW  VIGNALE : 27.000 km', 'R18 5x112 originalne Vw Seat Audi Skoda']
```